# Filters from App Builder to lightning component and represent that data in visualforce charts

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, report-chart

I have a Lightning component embedded in a VF  that is going to receive some filter parameters from app builder, in the apex controller I wanna get the charts data from a report using those filter parameters.

Is there a way to get that data filtered out in visualforce Charts?